# Client and server don't communicate if spawned on separate Eshell?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have these 2 Erlang modules:

Server:

```erlang
-module(server).

-export([start/0, loop/0]).

books(Cc) ->
  string:concat("Works ", Cc).

loans(Name) ->
  string:concat("Works too ", Name).

loop() ->
  receive
    {ClientPID, books, Info} ->
      ClientPID ! books(Info),
      loop();
    {ClientPID, loans, Info} ->
      ClientPID ! loans(Info),
      loop();
    _ ->
      io:fwrite("Invalid request received!~n"),
      loop()
  end.


start() ->
  spawn(server, loop, []).
```

and Client:

```erlang
-module(client).

-export([start/1, client/1]).

start(Server_Address) ->
  spawn(client, client, [Server_Address]).

client(Server_Address) ->
  Server_Address ! {self(), books, "potato"},
  receive
    Response ->
      io:format("CLIENT ~w: ~w~n", [self(), Response])
  end.
```

I call Pid = server:start() it gives me a correct Pid without any errors, but when I call either client:start(Pid) or client:client(Pid) in a different Eshell it just doesn't communicate(It works if called in the same Eshell, obviously).

I know I'm just doing something wrong, but what is it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely both nodes are not clustered, you may check which nodes belong to the cluster with [`nodes()`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#nodes-0)

In order to start nodes that are reachable, you must name them:

```sh
erl -sname client@localhost
```

and ping the other node:

```
$> erl -sname server@localhost                   
Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1]

Eshell V11.1  (abort with ^G)
(server@localhost)1> nodes().
[]
(server@localhost)2> net_adm:ping('client@localhost').
pong
(server@localhost)3> nodes().                         
[client@localhost]
```

Comment: The client/server are still unreachable even though both Eshell recognize each other, what am I missing?

Comment: @obvionaoe probably you're writing the Pid as it's reported by a shell into the other shell directly. When a `pid()` is printed, it's printed relative to the node that prints it, so although a pid for a node is `<0.98.0>`, from the other node it's `<8731.98.0>` (The first number is a reference to the node).  It's easier if the server [has a name](https://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#register-2), as it can be contacted as `{Name, Node} ! Message`

Comment: You can see the behaviour explained in the last comment if you run `spawn(hd(nodes()), fun() -> io:format("~p ~s~n", [self(), io_lib:format("~p", [self()])]) end).` in a clustered shell, this command spawns a process in the remote node that prints its pid and the remote node's representation of the same pid

Comment: `{Name, Node} ! Message ` what is the Node in this statement?

Comment: @obvionaoe It's a node name (`atom()`) as reported by `node()` or `nodes()`. If you run the same commands as with the response, it should be `{Name, 'server@localhost'}`

Comment: Ok, got it working now! Thanks a lot, you were a great help!